# Input field with scrollable dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm working on a search bar on a website where users can enter any phrase to an input field and based on the user input an Ajax query returns with a list of results no matter where the searched phrase exists in the text. As the user types I would like to create a scrollable drop down dynamically (because sometimes I have a huge set of results)  with the results from where the user can finally pick.

I did it with a `datalist` element but my problem is that `datalist` filters the results by default and shows only those records which start with the searched term. Not to mention that not all browsers support `datalist`.

My question would be if there's any out of the box solution for this or I have to do it with an input filed and a separate drop-down?

Just to give you a better example I'm looking for the very same search bar solution that google maps is doing.

Comment: There are lots of autocomplete and typeahead plugins for this. You can find plenty just by simple google search, but for example jQuery autocomplete plugin (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) will do. It is support across all main browsers and you can use it for remote search, so large data set is no problem.

Comment: @MarekTakac Thanks Marek. I'll take a look and post my findings here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MarekTakac I'm answering my own question based on his comment. Hopefully others who face the same issue will find this useful. [jqueryui.com/autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) did the trick. Below you can find my final solution and how I implemented it with ajax.

```
$("#searchboxinput").on("input",function() {
    // Ajax only initiated if min 1 character or more entered
    if ($(this).val().length !== 0) {
      $.ajax({
          url: "/index.php?r=site%2Fajax",
          type: "GET",
          data: "search=" + $(this).val(),
          success: function(data) {
              window.$vars.markersLayer.clearLayers();
              var availableTags = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].gps) {
                  availableTags.push(data[i].name);
                  latlong = data[i].gps.split(",");
                  var ltng = [];
                  ltng.push(parseFloat(latlong[0]));
                  ltng.push(parseFloat(latlong[1]));
                  marker = L.marker(ltng).bindPopup(data[i].name);
                  window.$vars.markersLayer.addLayer(marker);
                }
              }
              map.fitBounds(window.$vars.markersLayer.getBounds());
              $("#searchboxinput").autocomplete({
                  source: availableTags
              });
          },
      });
    }
    // If input field is empty we have to clear the markers
    // otherwise it would show all of them.
    else {
      window.$vars.markersLayer.clearLayers();
    }
});
```

I could manage to customize the look and feel of autocomplete dropdown by overwriting its CSS in my own style sheet file like this:

```
.ui-widget {
  z-index: 1010;
  font-family: "Lato", "Ubuntu", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#ui-id-1{
  top: 115px !important;
  left: 16px !important;
  width: 359px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
}

.ui-widget-content {
  border: 1px solid #e4e1e1;
}

.ui-state-focus {
  background: #eaeaea !important;
  border: 0px !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    width: 8px;
    height:5px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background:#FFFFFF;
    border: thin solid #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #FFFFFF inset;
    border-radius:0px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: lightgray;
    border: thin solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: lightgray;
}
```